# Как передать обьекты нескольких position RecyclerViewа в другой активити?

Tags: android

В общем, возник такой вопрос. У меня есть к примеру массив картинок, который я вывожу через адаптер. Я реализовал CLickListener для передачи картинки в другой активити, при нажатии собственно на объект. Собственно вопрос такой: Я хочу передать к примеру, несколько картинок в другой активити, допустим 4 картинки. То есть, логика такая: Я прожимаю несколько картинок, и хочу каким-то образом сохранить  данные этих картинок для передачи в другой активити. КАК можно этого добиться? Абсолютно не могу понять, подскажите пожалуйста, не хватает понимания взаимодействия. Надеюсь понятно, задал вопрос.
Вот нечто похожее на код. (Тут я пытался сохранить две картинки после второго клика)

```
public class AdapterFourDay extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AdapterFourDay.MyVieHolder> {

Context myContext;
private List<Objects> objectList;

private int click = 1;
boolean isFristClick = true;

public AdapterFourDay(Context myContext, List<Objects> objectList) {
    this.myContext = myContext;
    this.objectList = objectList;
}


@NonNull
@Override
public AdapterFourDay.MyVieHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view;

    LayoutInflater mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(myContext);

    view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.item_layout,parent,false);

    return new MyVieHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull AdapterFourDay.MyVieHolder holder, int position) {

    Glide.with(myContext).load(R.drawable.cover_card).into(holder.imageView);
    holder.descript.setText(objectList.get(position).getDescript());
    //setAnimation(holder.imageView,position);

    if (position== 52 || position== 51 || position== 50)
    {
        holder.imageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    if (position==48 || position==49 || position == 54 || position == 55)
    {
        holder.imageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }



    holder.imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
        click=click+1;
            if (isFristClick) {
                Toast.makeText(myContext, "Item no: " + position, LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        Glide.with(myContext).load(objectList.get(position).getCardImage()).into(holder.imageView);


            }
            if (click == 2)
            {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(myContext, OpenFourCard.class);
                        intent.putExtra("image2",objectList.get(position).getCardImage());


            }
            if(click>=3) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(myContext, OpenFourCard.class);
                intent.putExtra("image", objectList.get(position).getCardImage());
                myContext.startActivity(intent);
                isFristClick = false;
                holder.imageView.setOnClickListener(null);
            }


        }


    });
 }

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return objectList.size();
}

    public static class MyVieHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    private ImageView imageView;
    private TextView descript;
    private ConstraintLayout cardLayout;

    public MyVieHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        imageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.card_image);
        descript = itemView.findViewById(R.id.descript);
        cardLayout = itemView.findViewById(R.id.card_layout);
    }
}


 }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я бы не рекомендовал вам передавать такие данные через Bundle. Bundle предназначен для передачи простых типов данных ( id, строки и т.п). Да вы конечно же можете передать в нем что угодно реализовав в ваших классах интерфейсы Serializable или Parcelable, но важно помнить, что размер бандла ограничен (вроде бы 1МБ, но может быть сейчас и больше).

Вместо этого вам все же лучше создать какое-то хранилище для этих данных которое живет независимо от ваших активити и в бандле передавать только id или ссылку на ваши данные и снова доставать их их хранилища.

P.S.

Что может быть в роли хранилища?

- Это может быть синглтон который вы создаете в активити, а дальше просто дергаете его экзмепляр в разных точках приложения. [Здесь](https://habr.com/ru/post/27108/) можно почитать про паттерн синглтон. В целом это может и не быть синглтон, тут зависит от вашей архитектуры. Ну например у вас может быть активити а в ней будет 5 фрагментов, и вы можете создавать экземпляр класса в активити а из фрагментов обращаться к нему. Таким образом данные будут живы пока жива активити.
- Вы можете использовать SharedPreference, но он тоже предназначен больше для хранения простых данных, но эти данные вы сможете получить и после выгрузки приложения из памяти.
- Вы можете создать базу данных и в ней хранить ваши данные (Например Room или SQLite). Аналогично SharedPreference база хранит в себе данные независимо от жизни приложения.

Comment: как насчет синглтона с массивом? как считаете идея имеет место быть?

Comment: Если вам данные нужны только в пределах жизни приложения то синглтон вполне подойдёт. Если допустим они нужны только в пределах этих активити тот подумайте о том как его уничтожать если он больше нет нужен

Comment: Простите пожалуйста за глупый вопрос. А как можно создать эти хранилища?Я имею ввиду с помощью чего

Comment: ни через SharedPreferences?или это все же не очень решение?

Comment: Дополнил ответ.

Comment: Тут нужна конкретная задача. Способов много.

Comment: В общем , в моем случае у меня получилось сделать через SharedPreferences. Спасибо большое за ответы. Детальней изучу данный вопрос.

Comment: SharedPreference хранит ваши данные в памяти телефона. Если они вам не нужны после того как приложение закрывается, вам лучше все же создать класс который просто будет в себе хранить их (синглтон).

Answer (score 2):

Вам нужно формировать при выборе нескольких картинок такой же массив как вы получаете в адаптере:

```
private List<Objects> selectedObjects = ArrayList<Objects>();
```

при выборе картинки вы добавляете ее в массив:

```
selectedObjects.add(objectList.get(position))
```

и дальше передаете данный массив в активность:

```
intent.putExtra("image", selectedObjects);
```

так же стоит учитывать что при снятии выделения нужно удалять элемент из массива:

```
selectedObjects.remove(objectList.get(position));
```